# How to move data from a pop-up modal to a screen in react native?

Tags: react-native

The scenario is I have a pop-up modal and I am hitting some API and getting back some JSON data in the modal. I need the JSON data to be used on the screen that appears when the modal is closed. Is there a way to get data from the modal to screen?

Comment: u can use redux or state....

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to display some data from api in a component which isn't the one. in which you are making the API call right ?

Comment: Yeah, @HaykShakhbazyan, I am calling API in a modal and need to use it on a screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps.
in your case, redux will worked.

here is the package link: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux